# ¿Cómo se deben pronunciar las palabras que empiezan con "hue"?

Tags: pronunciación, fonología, diptongos

## Español

He notado que las letras "**hue**" de las palabras como: [hueso](http://www.forvo.com/word/hueso/#es), [huerta](http://www.forvo.com/word/huerta/#es) y [huevo](http://www.forvo.com/word/huevo/#es)  son pronunciadas como "**[w](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//w/)e**" (español) como el nombre "Wenceslao", al menos aquí en México, en lugar de "**ue**". Por ejemplo "we-so" en lugar de "ue-so".

¿Es esto un fenómeno fonético que se produce por ser diptongo?

¿Es esta la pronunciación correcta?

---

## Inglés

I've noticed that the letters "**hue**" from words such as: [hueso](http://www.forvo.com/word/hueso/#es), [huerta](http://www.forvo.com/word/huerta/#es) y [huevo](http://www.forvo.com/word/huevo/#es) are pronounced "**[w](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//w/)e**" (Spanish) as the name "Wenceslao", at least here in Mexico, instead of "**ue**". For example "we-so" instead of "ue-so".

Is this a phonetic phenom that is produced because of the diphthong?

Is this the correct pronunciation?

Comment: It probably would have made sense if I was familiar with the name *Wenceslao* :)

Comment: La respuesta de user983248 es acorde pero yo buscaria una distinción fonética para realizar la pregunta, porque me ha costado un poco entender lo que preguntabas ya que en mi dialecto, son lo mismo :)

Comment: Si quieres una buena aclaración, el sonido debe o debiera de ser el mismo para cualquier diptongo: por ejempo, "puede". Lo notable es la h "muda" en ese caso, no el diptongo. Pero es una buena pregunta, +1

Comment: I don't quite understand the question: 'ue' pronounced as `[we]` *is* a diphthong. Do you expect e.g. *hueso* to be pronounced as `[u.ˈe.so]` (i.e. in hiatus)?

Comment: Relacionado: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16620/18348

Answer (score 3):

## Español

Sí, es una malformación, de donde yo provengo es como "güe", [güevos], [güeso], [güerta], pero es solo una malformación fonética ya que la manera correcta de pronunciar la palabra es [uevos], [ueso], [uerta], la letra "H" no tiene sonido en estas palabras.

Sucede en todas las palabras que comienzan con hue como: hueco, huelga, huella, huelo, huérfano, huerta, hueso, huésped, huesudo, huevo/a.

Nota: puede ser güe o we.

Otro caso es el de las palabras que comienzan con LL, en algunos lugares puedes escuchar las palabras ser pronunciadas con Y (lluvia -> yuvia)

---

## English

Yep, it's a malformation, from where I come it's like /gue/ güevos, güeso, güerta, but it's just a malformation, a phonetic one, because the correct way to pronounce the word is /uevos/, /ueso/, /uerta/, since the "H" has no sound on these words.

It happens in all words starting hue, like: hueco, huelga, huella, huelo, huérfano, huerta, hueso, huésped, huesudo, huevo/a.

Note: it can be gue or we.

Another case is words starting with LL, in some places you can here these words been pronounced like Y (lluvia -> yuvia).

Comment: Excelente respuesta, pero yo no le llamaria malformacion, es tipico de los dialectos regionales.

Comment: ¿Querías decir en realidad "güe" en vez de "gue", pronunciando la u? Si es así, te faltaría la diéresis.

Comment: @JoulSauron nop, las dos formas son correctas dependiendo de la región. Ciertas regiones hacen un acento en la u por lo cual seria güe o gúe mientras que en otras regiones no hay una pronunciación o acentuación en la letra u por to que fonética-mente suena similar a we o gue, en menor numero existen regiones donde el acento se produce en la letra e.

Comment: Jeje, no es que sea correcta o no, es simplemente como se dice en algunos sitios. Ojo, sigo sin entenderte bien, así que por aclarar. Una cosa es güe o gúe (pronuciando siempre la u, independientemente del acento) y otra cosa es gue, sin pronunciar la u. Entonces, ¿dices que en algunos sitios "huevo" lo pronuncian como en "Guevara"? Es que dices fonéticamente como "we" o "gue", pero es que depende de cómo se pronuncie "we", puede ser como "ue", y entonces necesitas la diéresis. ¿Se dice o no se dice la u?

Comment: De paso, ¿podrías decir las regiones donde dicen "hue" lo dicen como "guepardo"?

Comment: Creo que te has liado mucho con la otografía y los acentos, jeje. Quieres decir que en tu región (en España también se dice así") se dice "güevo", es decir, la hache muda pasa a ser una gé. El acento sigue estándo en la e igualmente, si no sería "gúevo".

Comment: @user983248 Si usas por ejemplo "gúe" en lugar de "güe" no es lo mismo porque al añadir la tilde provocarías una separación en dos sílabas (gú-e). Por ejemplo la palabra cigüeña tiene 3 sílabas (ci-güe-ña). Si escribieras cigúeña* estarías creando cuatro sílabas (ci-gú-e-ña); ahora mismo no se me ocurre ninguna palabra a la que le ocurra esto en español. De todos modos "hue" es una sóla sílaba al igual que "güe", pero "gúe" son dos.

Comment: @JoulSauron Quien te dijo que soy de España ? Soy Latino.

Comment: @Javi Los acentos a los que hice referencia en mi comentario son meramente como referencia a las diferentes formas de pronunciación NO GRAMATICALMENTE CORRECTO, es simplemente una representación gramatical de como fonética mente se pronuncia la misma palabra en DISTINTAS REGIONES

Comment: @JoulSauron Quien te dijo que soy de España ? Soy Latino.
güevo, gúevo, guevo, guévo son la misma cosa, pero la pronunciación no cambia el objeto o significado. No todos los dialectos, acentos, y/o variaciones del idioma español pronuncian la misma palabra de la misma manera. Esta es una de esas palabras.

Answer (score 3):

In some words in Spanish there is a degree of free-variation amongst dialects/speakers as to whether orthographic diphthongs are pronounced as diphthongs or hiatus (e.g. *biólogo, enviaron, truhan, buhero*). The following paper discusses examples of [i ~ j] extensively:

- [*From hiatus to diphthong: the evolution of vowel sequences in Romance*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/47087325.pdf)

The usual pronunciation for the sequence 'ue' in Spanish is the diphthong [we]. 'u' only appears in hiatus when it is itself stressed (i.e. in the sequence 'úa', 'úe',<sup>1</sup> 'úo' etc<sup>2</sup>) or dialectically (as noted above) in some words, though the only examples that come to mind are those where 'u' appears in the sequence 'uhV́' ('h' historic /h/, now silent).

However, in some dialects (e.g. Mexican) word-initial /w/ (orthographic 'hu-') [is pronounced](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=h) as [gw] or [bw]. This can be seen in the following alternate orthographies/derived words:

| hu | gü |
| --- | --- |
| huero | [güero](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=g%C3%BCero) |
| huemul | güemul |
| huilo | [güilo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JphYZtR) |
| huillí | güillín |
| huillota | güillota |

---

<sup>1. The sequence 'úe' where the 'u' is stressed and both vowels are in hiatus [ˈu.e] occurs only marginally in a handful of loanwords/latinisms: *esprúe, lúe(s), rúe* and in old Salamancan orthographies of *buey*: *búe* but note even this orthography alternates with the expected [*bue*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6EAJ5UA).</sup>
<sup>2. *búho, dúho*</sup>

Comment: Interestingly in Asturian the effect was so strong as to insert a G in undiphthongized forms (probably helped by the /g/ being a uvular plosive). *oler* this becomes *goler* meaning *tener/percibir golor*, *esti güel a peste*. So likely this process was not particularly recent.