# ¿Es correcto pronunciar "hiede" con una h sonora?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, pronunciación

No sé si sea correcto, pero le he escuchado a mucha gente (e inconscientemente es la primera pronunciación que se me ocurre cuando pienso en la palabra) la pronunciación de *hiede* con una **h** sonora (aspirada, como la *h* del inglés).

Todas las fuentes de pronunciación que tengo me dan sólo el verbo en infinitivo. ¿Cuál es la pronunciación oficial y, en caso de que *h* sea sonora, a qué se debe?

Comment: Quite related: [_Do any dialects of Spanish still pronounce "h"?_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32742/12637)

Answer (score 6):

Como habitante de Andalucía y hablante del andaluz, debo decir que, en algunas ocasiones, sí que tendemos a pronunciar la `h`, pero sobre todo con propósito de exageración (cómo no). No sé si las veces que has oído pronunciar la `h` haya sido a personas andaluzas, en todo caso. Aquí la `h` *pronunciada* suena muy parecida a la *h* del inglés, pero en nuestro caso el origen es más árabe. Ya que en otra respuesta se menciona el *hierro*, en Andalucía se usa la expresión `a hierro` para indicar *a tope*, *a por todas*, pero pronunciada "a jierro" (la `j` pronunciada como se ha indicado). También se puede escuchar decir *qué jambre tengo*, por ejemplo.

Sobre la palabra concreta de la pregunta, `hiede`, aquí se usa para indicar que algo huele muy mal, pero pronunciada más bien como *jiere*, suavizando la *d* en una *r*. No estoy seguro, pero posiblemente sea un juego de palabras con el verbo *herir*, ya que un olor así *hiere* los sentidos. Un ejemplo se puede escuchar en la canción *La mamaita* del grupo *Mojinos Escozíos*, al final del todo de la canción.

La pronunciación oficial es, en todo caso y como han indicado ya, con la `h` muda.

Answer (score 5):

Según el [**DRAE**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JutD8qE):

> ... en la lengua estándar actual [la "h"] **no representa sonido alguno**, si bien se aspira en determinadas voces de origen extranjero, como *hámster* o *dírham*, y en algunas zonas españolas y americanas como rasgo dialectal.

El [**Diccionario panhispánico de dudas**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=h) recoge, además, que aunque no es usual pronunciar "h" aspirada, sí muchos dialectos suelan pronunciar "hie-" inicial como "ye-":

> ... **El grupo *hi*** en posición inicial de palabra seguido de una e tónica se pronuncia normalmente como el **sonido palatal sonoro /y/** ... salvo detrás de pausa o de palabra que termina en vocal, en que **la pronunciación oscila entre [ié] y [yé]**; así, es normal que palabras como *hierro, hielo, hierba, hiedra* se pronuncien [yérro, yélo, yérba, yédra]...

Comment: Hay una diferencia entre ser estándar y ser correcto. Obviamente, al que viene de una zona que aspira las haches no es incorrecta dicha pronunciación. Ya que *heder* viene del latín *fœdere*, en dichas zonas, la aspiración de la *h* sería etimológicamente correcta.

Answer (score 5):

La *h* no se pronuncia en castellano. Es muy posible que las pronunciaciones exageradas andaluzas a las que se alude en otra de las respuestas no se deban en absoluto a la persistencia de un rastro de la antigua /h/ inicial (que no necesariamente proviene de /f/; cf. *hielo* < latín *gelus*), sino a motivos fonéticos sincrónicos (actuales).

En castellano las sílabas formadas por *hi-* más vocal son fonéticamente similares a las que comienzan por *y-* más vocal (*hierro* ~ *yerro*). En muchas regiones hispanoparlantes las palabras como *hierro* tienen un sonido semiconsonántico o semivocálico, [j] ~ [i̯], mientras que las otras tienen un sonido más o menos fricativo que puede hacerse incluso africado, [ʝ] ~ [ɟʝ]. Ambos sonidos se articulan en el mismo punto de la boca (el paladar) y en algunos dialectos se confunden.

Es posible que una pronunciación enfática de [je] termine sonando como [ʝe]~[ʝi̯e]. La vocal /i/ es palatal, de manera que el mero sonido [ʝ] la incluye, por así decirlo. Por su significado la palabra *hiede* se presta a esta clase de afectación fonética, que puede ser expresiva (el énfasis fonético expresa el asco que produce el hedor en cuestión).

Answer (score 0):

En mi region Cajamarca - Perú, muchos pobladores rurales aspiran la "h" en contadas palabras: Heder, hiede, hirviendo, hediondo, hoyo, honda(referido al arma antingua, no la marca japonesa), halar, etc.